# How to find out who handles a permalink?

Tags: permalinks

My [previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128836/what-is-causing-my-redirect) isn't faring too well. I guess it may be too specific. Let me approach the problem from another direction.

There's an URL within my Wordpress site. It's occupied - sending the visitor to some resource.

How can I identify the type of resource is associated with this URL, and then find the actual resource - page, category, post, whatever else might be holding up that URL?

The link is not specific, no `/tag/`, `/category/` or such on the path. It's probably a custom permalink attached to some entity. I need to find that entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I get the question correctly. Anyway, I will try. Correct me if I'm wrong.

What I understand your question is that you want to know which template is serving your URL. If that's what you mean by resource, you should check out [displaying current template path](http://jamesfishwick.com/display-current-template-path/). It basically throw the template filename in `head` section.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'display_template');
function display_template() {
    global $template;
    $filename = basename($template);
    echo '<strong>'.$filename.'</strong>';
}
```

**N.B:** It should only be used for development purpose.

You can also determine the type of resource seeing the template.

Comment: Thanks. Now as I noticed what happens, I'm getting a 404 error. And specifically for that name - I can change the shortlinks in posts to anything else and it works just fine, but any post with that URL for a shortlink gets a 404.